# POST request in Alamofire swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

am unable to make nested dict, please help me out

```
{
     "OneStopFlight" : "false",
     "TokenId" : "86839fb9-ed93-46d3-b480-c58dbc441838",
     "AdultCount" : "1",
     "InfantCount" : "0",
     "JourneyType" : "1",
     "EndUserIp" : "192.168.10.10",
     "DirectFlight" : "false",
     "Segments" : [
       {
         "PreferredDepartureTime" : "2018-06-27T00:00:00",
         "Origin" : "PNQ",
         "EndUserIp" : "192.168.10.10",
         "Destination" : "VNS",
         "FlightCabinClass" : "1"
       }
     ],
     "ChildCount" : "0"
    }
```

Comment: Try my answer...

Comment: You want to make such Dict as Parameter for API or you want to get this JSON Response Values ?

Comment: is this query solved ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create such dictionary as did showed above , you can create it easily as below

```
let segmentDict : [[String:Any]] = [
    [
       "PreferredDepartureTime" : "2018-06-27T00:00:00",
       "Origin" : "PNQ",
       "EndUserIp" : "192.168.10.10",
       "Destination" : "VNS",
       "FlightCabinClass" : "1"
    ]
]

let paramDict : [String:Any] = [
      "OneStopFlight" : "false",
      "TokenId" : "86839fb9-ed93-46d3-b480-c58dbc441838",
      "AdultCount" : "1",
      "InfantCount" : "0",
      "JourneyType" : "1",
      "EndUserIp" : "192.168.10.10",
      "DirectFlight" : "false",
      "Segments" : segmentDict,
      "ChildCount" : "0"
]

let segmentWithMultipleDict : [[String:Any]] = [
   [
      "PreferredDepartureTime" : "2018-06-27T00:00:00",
      "Origin" : "PNQ",
      "EndUserIp" : "192.168.10.10",
      "Destination" : "VNS",
      "FlightCabinClass" : "1"
    ],
    [
      "PreferredDepartureTime" : "2018-06-27T00:00:00",
      "Origin" : "PNQ",
      "EndUserIp" : "192.168.10.10",
      "Destination" : "VNS",
      "FlightCabinClass" : "1"
    ]
]
```

In case if you want to Deque such data

```
struct dequeResponse
{
    var OneStopFlight : String = ""
    var TokenId : String = ""
    var AdultCount : String = ""
    var InfantCount : String = ""
    var JourneyType : String = ""
    var EndUserIp : String = ""
    var DirectFlight : String = ""
    var Segments : [segment] = []
    var ChildCount : String = ""


    func getDataFromJSON(_ data: [String:Any]) -> dequeResponse{
        var myResponseValues = dequeResponse()
        if let value = data["OneStopFlight"] as? String {
            myResponseValues.OneStopFlight = value
        }

        if let value = data["TokenId"] as? String {
            myResponseValues.TokenId = value
        }

        if let value = data["AdultCount"] as? String {
            myResponseValues.AdultCount = value
        }

        if let value = data["InfantCount"] as? String {
            myResponseValues.InfantCount = value
        }

        if let value = data["JourneyType"] as? String {
            myResponseValues.JourneyType = value
        }

        if let value = data["EndUserIp"] as? String {
            myResponseValues.EndUserIp = value
        }

        if let value = data["DirectFlight"] as? String {
            myResponseValues.DirectFlight = value
        }

        if let value = data["Segments"] as? [[String:Any]] {
            let newSegment = segment()
            myResponseValues.Segments = newSegment.getDataFromJSON(value)
        }

        if let value = data["ChildCount"] as? String {
            myResponseValues.ChildCount = value
        }

        return myResponseValues
    }
}

struct segment {
    var PreferredDepartureTime : String?
    var Origin : String?
    var EndUserIp : String?
    var Destination : String?
    var FlightCabinClass : String?

    func getDataFromJSON(_ data: [[String:Any]]) -> [segment] {
        var segmentAray = [segment]()
        for i in 0..<data.count {
            var myCurrentSegment = segment()
            if let value = data[i]["PreferredDepartureTime"] as? String {
                myCurrentSegment.PreferredDepartureTime = value
            }

            if let value = data[i]["Origin"] as? String {
                myCurrentSegment.Origin = value
            }

            if let value = data[i]["EndUserIp"] as? String {
                myCurrentSegment.EndUserIp = value
            }

            if let value = data[i]["Destination"] as? String {
                myCurrentSegment.Destination = value
            }

            if let value = data[i]["FlightCabinClass"] as? String {
                myCurrentSegment.FlightCabinClass = value
            }
            segmentAray.append(myCurrentSegment)
        }
        return segmentAray
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var jsonObject = dequeResponse()
jsonObject = jsonObject.getDataFromJSON(paramDict)
print(jsonObject.Segments)
```

**Note** If this doesn't meet your requirement please edit question with more detail